# homestead.yaml not found in homestead folder

Tags: git, laravel-5.1

I follow the tutorial in laracast about configuring homestead.

I created folder called `myprojects` in `c:/` drive
then I do `cd myprojects`, once I get inside I issue the following command in cmd `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`

After downloading the file, the tutoirial says edit the `homestead.yaml` but I could not find in the directory. I am installing this in windows 8.1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: once you clone the repo, you should run `bash init.sh` did you do that ?

Comment: @FredericHenri yes , it says,cp:overwrite /c/Users/myuserame/.homestead/Homestead.yaml ?

Comment: @FredericHenri, why it goest to that directory ? not in c:/myproject/ ?